# How to design a JSON object class in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am trying to deserialize Json object. I created below class for deserialization. but getting error.

I was getting below error.

*To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"Title":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.*

Here is my class ans Json object.

```
[{
    "Id": "100",
    "Title": "Adults",
    "Order": "1"
},
{
    "Id": "101",
    "Title": "Kids",
    "Order": "2"
},
]



public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
    }

  Rootobject _Rail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(strJson);
```

Comment: Can you supply the error you are getting as well?

Comment: Providing information could be helpful. But what's that comma doing there? `},
]`

Comment: @TS I have many array Items. I don't want to copy all 1000 items. while removing one comma left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RootObject should jus look like

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
}
```

You can always use **[`json2csharp`](http://json2csharp.com/)** tool to convert.

and the code should be as,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Comment: Error at Converstion. Cannot convert system.generic.List to RootObject

Comment: Error: To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.